# How do I ground my LED retrofit in a ceiling can?

Tags: electrical, led, recessed-lighting, retrofit

I've got what appears to be a low height 5" can above the kitchen sink.  There is a 60W IC bulb in there.  It looks really trashy since the cover is missing.  So, I picked up one of those ceiling LED retrofit kits to put in there for the power savings and to make it look decent.

It looks like it's going to be a very tight squeeze, but *should* barely fit.  My issue though is that the LED kit says it must be grounded to the can.  They list 3 methods:

1. Attach supplied ground to stud in can.

   Well, no stud in my can.  No go there.
2. Attach supplied ground with supplied screw to existing ground hole in can.

   There is a hole in the can, but it's MUCH bigger around than the supplied screw and it's not anywhere deep enough for the supplied screw either.  In addition, it's so low in the can that I don't know that the assembly will even go into place with a screwhead there.  Presumably it was designed for a safety wire to be attached there to keep a cover from falling to the ground and shattering.  Probably not a good idea.
3. Attach supplied ground to one of the can height adjustment screws.

   This sounds promising.  Except the ground is ring connector...  If I pull one of those can height adjustment screws all the way out, will I be able to put it back into place, or is there a nut on the back that will fall down and cause me grief?  I've considered cutting a notch in the ring connector to avoid that situation, but I don't want to hack up the kit any in case of a warranty issue.

So how can I properly ground the fixture?

Comment: Do you know if the can itself is properly grounded? If so, a ground wire attached by a screw to anywhere on the metal body of the can should suffice.

Comment: I have no idea if the can is properly grounded.  If not, all this is moot, since all the standard attachment methods depend on the can being grounded...  :-)

Comment: Then just find a convenient spot, drill a pilot hole and attach a self tapping grounding screw. Attach the green wire, using a crimp-on connector and you are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warranty? For 3), cut the ring connector. Don't cut a hunk out, just split it. Use dykes. Then you can bend it (like a key ring spreads) around the bolt and when you tighten it, it will flatten out again as a ring and won't fall off. But that's not the most secure place to connect (i.e., the height adjustment screws don't tighten very tight). Any other location for securing this connection to the can is probably a better choice (e.g., for 2), use self-tapping screw next to the hole that's too large).